# Migrate error in Terminal, can't add data/create tables in Django database

Tags: python, django

**UPDATE #2 - Dec 13 (STILL NEED HELP)**

The Github repo for the project: https://github.com/onlyandrewn/gale

From what I understand looking at my Terminal, it seems to keep referring to previous migrations after I try to `./manage.py makemigrations blog` and `./manage.py migrate blog`

The problem may stem from an old error for non nullable fields when I mistakenly put a string into a field called `order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()` which should have been an integer. Now, I would like to add a new field called rank, and I go through the process of ./manage.py makemigrations blog and ./manage.py migrate blog but I keep getting prompted with this in the Terminal:

```
You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

When I do run python manage.py, I get this long list of stuff in my Terminal:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: blog
Running migrations:
  **Applying blog.0007_auto_20141212_1622...Traceback (most recent call last):**
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 160, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=options.get("fake", False))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 63, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(migration, fake=fake)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 97, in apply_migration
    migration.apply(project_state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 107, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, project_state, new_state)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 139, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 473, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type, old_db_params, new_db_params, strict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 190, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_fields=[(old_field, new_field)])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 135, in _remake_table
    self.quote_name(model._meta.db_table),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/schema.py", line 99, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 81, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 485, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column order is not unique**
```

Two things that stand out to me in this long slew of text:

`Applying blog.0007_auto_20141212_1622...Traceback (most recent call last):` **(The current migration is closer to 25, #7 is a very old migration)**

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column order is not unique
```

Comment: What is the problem here? Are you asking how to clear the content of your terminal? If so, it's just `clear`

Comment: I just get this error everytime I run ./manage.py migrate blog

Answer (score 0):

after run `makemigrations` django put 'http://' in your field definition, creating a wrong migration

check your `migrations` directory,  edit the last one and manually remove  'http://' from the field definition

EDIT:

the migration 0007 create a unique consttraint on the field `order` but your db already contains duplicates so that migration cannot succeed.

you have a totally inconsistent situation, as your system is under development (ie not yet released) it's better that you remove all the migrations, remove the db a run `makemigrations` again.

Comment: What should I put in the field instead?

Comment: simply change the `default='http://'` to `default=0` ora any other value you put in your Model definition

Comment: can you share your last migration code and the database used ?

Comment: Yeah, I just updated my question on Stackoverflow and I've put a link to the Github repo, which is here: https://github.com/onlyandrewn/gale

Answer (score 0):

```
order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

means `IntegerField` and **NOT** Text- or CharField.

and you gave `"http://"` which IS string.

change this to default number like `0` or `0000` whatever..

and run migrations again

"*I'm wondering how to get rid of it in the Terminal.*" - you better wonder how to fix the problem then it goes away from your terminal